# "process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 2282" How to solve this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to load my application in device but i got message like shown in image.
[image]

How can i solve it ?? I am using xCode 6.4

Answer (score 23):

I am assuming you are running on device. Using a different provisioning profile solved this issue key point is to use a Developer profile rather than a Distribution profile.

Comment: Thanks. I have created new development profile and its work now perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this dialog came along in an Objective-C project using Swift pods.
We debug directly the Release configuration.
If this is the case what fixed my problem was to turn off optimizations of 'Swift Compiler - Code Generation' for Release:
[image: Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Optimization Level]