# xcode build and error "process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 5747"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

My coworker recently clone my project and run it, it show up this error message, Is there any key work that I can find error code message description?

[image]

Comment: when you say "clone and run it", did your co-worker clone it onto a different machine, a different account, or did they duplicate the folder and move it to a different place on the same hard drive & user account as the original folder?  What happens when you restart the machine or delete the original app from the simulator?

Comment: I exported apple account and import it into his machine and all provisioning profiles was new download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a Development Provisioning profile to run your app on a device...

For more info you can check this thread:

["process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 2282" How to solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881138/process-launch-failed-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process-2282-how-to-solve-th)

or this

[Xcode 5: failed to get the task for process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913676/xcode-5-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process)

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it via using Development Provisioning profile